Invalid [to product id] Error in 2checkout Subscription upgrade Soap API
I have created 2 recurring products in the 2checkout, and via Inline cart i have purchased 1st Product, So Order and subscription automatically created in the 2checkout.
Now I want to upgrade the Subscription via Soap Client API of 2checkout,
I have successfully created SessionID, And using the Recently created subscriptionId and ProductCode I am giving the ProductCode of recently created subscription(also used thr different product codes as well)
And Ran
$client->subscriptionupgradeFunction(sessionId, SubscriptionId, ProductCode)
But all I get it Invalid[to product id]
I am confused in the products Id
Which one to use
The criteria of product to be used in the subscription upgradation
Please help
I am expecting to upgrade the Subscription but getting the error
Invalid to product Id
